# How to find explicit quadratic equation for a sequence of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would you prove that if you have a sequence of numbers, and the difference between the difference of terms is constant, the explicit equation can be written as a quadratic? How would you find this explicit equation.

For example, I have the sequence: 2,5,11,20,32,... and I want to 1) show that this is a quadratic and 2) find the explicit equation.

Can you extend this method to higher power sequences?

Comment: https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10002.3-5.shtml

Answer (score 1):

The differences between your terms are 3,6,9,12 respectively. So we can write a difference equation $$a_{n+1}=a_n+3n$$ with $a_1=2$. Since the difference between terms in a polynomial, we can postulate that $a_n$ is a polynomial. $$a_n=b_0+b_1n+b_2n^2+\cdots+b_mn^m$$for some $m$, and some coefficients $b_i$. Then $$b_1+b_2((n+1)^2-n^2)+\cdots+b_m((n+1)^m-n^m)=3n$$Equating powers and comparing coefficients, we see we need no more than $b_1,b_2\ne 0$. $b_i$ is zero for $i>2$. Then $$b_1+(2n+1)b_2\equiv 3n$$This can then be solved with the initial condition.

---

The reason why this was a quadratic was because the difference between terms was linear. If we had $$a_{n+1}=a_n+k\cdot n^p$$for some constant $k$ and some power $p$, then by the same argument, we would get $$a_n=b_0+b_1n+\cdots + b_{p+1}n^{p+1}$$