# very basic linear non-homogeneous recurrence relation where difference increases by 1 each recursion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find a formula for this sequence.
2, 4, 7, 11, 16, ...

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

$a_{n} – a_{n-1} = n$

Homogeneous case  $a_{n} – a_{n-1} = 0$:
Characteristic equation $r – 1 = 0$  gives $1^n$ is a solution

Non-homogeneous case $a_n – a_{n-1} = n$:
Let $b_n = cn + d$ be a solution

Then $cn + d   –   c(n-1) - d = n$

So $(c - c - 1)n + (d   – d) = 0$

Comment: $b_n=(n^2+n+2)/2$

Comment: You did "Let $b_n=cn+d$". This form of the solution will not work, since you've assumed a constant difference between terms.

Comment: @JohnDoe Why is that?  I thought that if you have a polynomial on the right side, you insert a polynomial of same degree and unknown coefficients into the equation.  Is this not true?

Comment: No - in general you should introduce a polynomial of degree 1 higher, and with unknown coefficients as usual.

Comment: @user3146 to understand why, see [this recent answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3160798/399334).

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh, thanks!

Comment: @JohnDoe what do I make of the unknown coefficient of the constant term canceling (therefore giving no solution for it)?  $cn^2 + dn + e – c(n-1)^2 – d(n-1) - e = n$

Comment: @user3146 you use your original sequence. you can compute the other terms, then pick the constant so that the term $a_n$ gives the correct thing. This is analogous to picking a $y$ intercept for differential equations - all possible choices are solutions to the equation, but only one will fit your specific problem. In this example, that is $$a_1=2$$

Comment: @JohnDoe  Okay, so you don't necessarily just add the homogeneous and non-homogenous solutions.  They can overlap, the way you can have $x^3 + xy + g(y)$ when integrating a partial with respect to x, and  $y^2 + xy + h(x)$ when integrating the partial with respect to y, and combine them to get $f(x,y) = y^2 + xy + x^3 + c$.  Is this right?  Or, do I just add them and use initial conditions (sequence values) and solve for the constant coefficient to get that the constant coefficient is zero?

Comment: @user3146 this is more analogous to the case of a differential equation of a single variable, where you use an initial condition to determine the constant. Also, as an aside, note that the homogeneous solution you got isn't just $1^n$ - it is $C\cdot 1^n=C$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Then, you could think of the solution to this to be the sum of the homogeneous and non-homogeneous solutions (hmg solution being $An^2+Bn$, non hmg soln being $C$).